# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ERROR

Tags: python, anaconda

I'm using Windows 10, and installed Python 3.7.3 using Anaconda3.

I need the following package for using Dakota:

- numpy
- scipy
- pandas

I tested that the python environment is set up properly by executing import numpy, import scipy, and import pandas in command prompt window. I also added the path to environment variable.

However, the python package in Dakota does not work correctly.  When I start Python with the python command and then execute the import dakota command, the dakota package is not imported and the following error shows:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dakota'`

Comment: Have you tried using `conda list` or `pip list` to see if dakota is actually installed? That error means python couldn't find the package at all

Comment: either it isn't installed or it's installed in a location thats not in your path

Comment: I just tried conda list and pip list , Dakota is not included. However, when I try to execute Dakota in command window out of python environment, it says Dakota has been installed.

Comment: then it hasn't been installed in your "base" anaconda environment or whatever environment you're using...read here to make sure you install to the proper environment from anaconda prompt https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html...if that doesn't work..try doing import pip._internal as pip..then pip.main(['install','dakota']) from python in proper environment

Comment: or just copy the package into the folder where all your packages are stored for the proper environment :D

Comment: python is in C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe and Dakota is in C:\SimCenter\Dakota\bin\dakota.exe and both directories have been added to system variable path

Comment: I am kind of new in this area. I just put Dakota and Anacorda in the same folder but still not working.